# Imagemagick - how do you scale Image A to fit on top of a certain part of Image B?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Starting from Input `image B` below, how do you resize input `image A` to on the right side of `image B` while retaining the transparent text of `image B`?

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
$a_resized = resizeImagePath('imagea.jpg',32,128,imagick::FILTER_BOX,1,1,false);
$a_resized = resizeImage($a_resized,256,630,imagick::FILTER_GAUSSIAN,1,1,false);
// echo $img->getImageBlob(); // works

$b_raw = new Imagick(realpath('image0transparent.png'));
$b_raw2 = new Imagick(realpath('image0transparent.png'));

$a_resized->setImageGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_EAST);

$b_raw->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$b_raw->setImageArtifact('compose:args', "1,0,-0.5,0.5");
$b_raw->compositeImage($a_resized, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 946, 0);
$b_raw->compositeImage($b_raw2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
echo $b_raw->getImageBlob();;///->writeImage("./output.png");

//https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_resize
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php
function resizeImagePath($imagePath, $width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit, $cropZoom) {
    return resizeImage(new Imagick(realpath($imagePath)), $width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit, $cropZoom);
}
 function resizeImage($imagick, $width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit, $cropZoom) {
    //The blur factor where > 1 is blurry, < 1 is sharp. 
    $w = $imagick->getImageWidth();
    $h = $imagick->getImageHeight();
    $width = $w/$h*$height;

    $imagick->resizeImage($width, $height, $filterType, $blur, $bestFit);

    $cropWidth = $imagick->getImageWidth();
    $cropHeight = $imagick->getImageHeight();

    if ($cropZoom) {
        $newWidth = $cropWidth / 2;
        $newHeight = $cropHeight / 2;

        $imagick->cropimage(
            $newWidth,
            $newHeight,
            ($cropWidth - $newWidth) / 2,
            ($cropHeight - $newHeight) / 2
        );

        $imagick->scaleimage(
            $imagick->getImageWidth() * 4,
            $imagick->getImageHeight() * 4
        );
    }
 
    return $imagick; 
}
```

Image A

[image]

Image B (right part is transparent with text overlay):

[image]

Desired result: Image A over B:

[image]

Here is `image B` where pink represents transparency:

[image]

Comment: Please be a bit more specific or show actual input and output results for your two cases. I do not understand what you want?  Do you want image A to be resized to so that its height is the same as the height of image B?

Comment: updated to show this

Comment: You have labelled your desired result as *"image A over B"*, but it is actually image B over A since the white text of B is occluding the blurry A underneath it. Isn't it?

Comment: Please clarify how to go about resizing of A. Must A be resized to some dimensions you know and have? Or to the same height as B? Or is the actual problem to work out the extent of the transparent part of B and resize to match that?

Comment: Same height as B, fitting in the space allotted. Possibly some cropping to fit in the transparent space.

Comment: It being in PHP makes this somewhat easier - all you have to do is 1) get the height of B, then 2) resize A, then 3) composite one over the other. If you show your code, we can see which part you are having trouble with. Thank you.

Comment: updated with what i've tried - it doesn't seem very efficient since i am applying composite multiple times to the same transparent image

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do that in ImageMagick command line. You can do the equivalent with PHP Imagick.

Resize image A to the height of image B. Then composite the resized image A at the right side of image B using compose method dstOver).

*Please show your code so we can help further.*

A.png

[image]

B.png

[image]

```
convert B.png \( A.png -resize x630 \) -gravity east -compose dstOver -composite x.png
```

[image]

Comment: how do you use -gravity east with composite?

Comment: how do you have the existing transparent part with the text show over imagea on the right? without calling $b_raw->compositeImage($b_raw2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0); twice?

Comment: I am not an expert on Imagick, but see the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setgravity.php for setGravity. Perhaps that will work.

Comment: I have revised my answer to use -compose dstOver.

Comment: yes i read the manual page for php setGravity before posting - there does not appear to be very many examples of how setGravity works with composite?

Comment: `$a_resized->setImageGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_EAST);` does nothing btw. i ended up just having to fudge the pixels above

Comment: Did you try setting it for $b? Otherwise, I guess you would have to compute the location in compositeImage which would be at the right side of the blue-green area.